# Who is the tag creator when it was added as an edit?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

["Create Tags" privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) explains that tags are created upon creating a question.

> **How do I create a new tag?**
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created.

If I enter a completely new tag *while editing* another user's question - who then is considered the author of the tag?

Comment: "Any user with at least [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) may create a tag on Stack Overflow.

To do this, one must apply it directly to a new or existing question. This is done by typing the new tag into the question's tag field and then submitting the post or edit. The person who adds the new tag will be recorded as the creator of that tag."